# How to plot the following print?

Tags: plotting

(Note: I am new to mathematica)

I am using this code

[code](http://txt.do/d1axc)

[APO-48-10](http://www.mapleprimes.com/DocumentFiles/235891_Answer/APO-48-10.txt)

It has prints but i would like to know how i can plot this? I know there is a plot function inside the code but its not yielding a plot when i run it.

I know it can be plotted since the author of the code used this command to plot several graph, with different input values given in "<< APO-48-10.txt;".

Comment: Do you have the "APO-48-10.txt" file? Without this file it's not possible to plot anything.

Comment: yes i do have the file

Comment: Can you share the file?

Comment: Find yourself a copy of "APO-48-10.txt", Google finds a few copies of that if you enclose that name in double quotes. Put that file in one of the places that Mathematica will look (Or you can prepend a path onto that name and put the file anywhere). Probably edit the contents of the file to adjust the parameters to fit your situation. Evaluate the notebook and then evaluate APOh[,,,] with the appropriate value substituted for ... And you should see your plot

Comment: i have the file

Comment: uploaded the other file

Comment: the file is rather large!

Comment: Provide examples for the inputs requested by the program

Answer (score 1):

The following modifications to the code should make it functional. I don't understand what the code does, however, nor what the inputs mean, so I have no idea whether the results are any good.

1. Instead of `<<APO-48-10.txt;`, use `Get["c:\path\to\your\APO-48-10.txt"];`
2. Towards the end of the code, you will find `Plot[{Bp, B[n], Bpade[n]}, ...];`. The output of this plot, however, is suppressed by `;` at the end of the line. A quick-and-dirty fix to see the plot can be had by adding a `Print` statement: `Print@Plot[{Bp, B[n], Bpade[n]}, ...];`.

After making those changes, and picking some random numbers as input, I get the following output:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: after i input Get["c:\path\to\your\APO-48-10.txt"]; i get syntax error for "unknown string escape \U etc.."

Comment: where did you put in the random numbers as input ?

Comment: i dont get any output like you did

Comment: @user10699 `"c:\path..."` is only a placeholder. You need to insert the path to your own APO-48-10.txt file is located. Did you do that? You can use the menu Insert -> File path to insert a correctly escaped file path on your system.

Comment: yes i did that and it worked but now i dont know where to insert the input in the code, should it be in the " temp[0] = Input[];" and for example 5  " temp[0] = Input[5];"?

Comment: where should the input values be in the code?

Comment: @user10699 Not really. You should then execute the code by evaluating `APOh[someValue]`; then the code will ask for values and input dialogs will appear where you can enter those values. You could hard-wire those values by replacing them in the code, but that's up to you and the functionality you want to achieve.

Comment: i canged APOh[5] then evaluated the entire formula but its not asking me for anything nor ploting anything ..very frustrating

Comment: Do you know how to evaluate code? Try pressing Shift+Enter when the cursor is on that line. You need to familiarize yourself with the very basics of *Mathematica* before you can do more with it. Perhaps start here: [Practicalities of the Wolfram Language](http://www.wolfram.com/language/elementary-introduction/practicalities-of-using-the-wolfram-language.html).

Comment: ,on which line?

Comment: i am using mathematica 11

Comment: very frustrating i must say

Comment: did you  choose n=4 ?

Comment: @user10699 The values of the parameters I chose are shown in the output, under "Input Parameters".

Comment: no input dialogs appears when i run the code :(